# What is the difference between MVC 2 and MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What are few differences between Asp.Net MVC 3 and MVC 2 framework.

Answer (score 11):

Here is the definitive answer!

http://www.asp.net/mvc/mvc3#overview

Answer (score 1):

Also make sure to read the [Release Notes](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes) for breaking changes. There are a few API and runtime changes that might cause existing applications to not work any more.